# load csv into leaflet and convert coordinates with proj4

Tags: javascript, csv, leaflet, proj

This question involves the use of:

- leaflet.js (used to create my map)
- leaflet omnivore plugin (used to load my csv data file)
- and proj4 (used to convert easting/northing to lat/lon)

My code below loads a stamen map with leaflet, and then uses omnivore to load my csv file.

In order to display the csv geo data on my map i need to first convert the easting/northing coordinates to lat/lon. The next sections of code contain the logic to do this, and it works successfully for the single coordinate sample within the console.log at the bottom.

But I have no idea how to use this logic on my full csv file. There is one column for easting, one for northing in the file - ultimately i want to my code to convert all these to lat lon, and plot them as points on my map.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.44, -1.01], 8);

L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner-background/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', 
{
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    minZoom: 8,
    maxZoom: 20,
    ext: 'png'
}).addTo(map);

var dataset = omnivore.csv('assets_cwy_new simple.csv');

var osgb = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs ';
var wgs84 = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ';

console.log(proj4(osgb,wgs84,[514545.49,215008.4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out, you can use [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) plugin with [Proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) to convert your easting/northing coordinates into WGS84 lng/lat. Do not forget to revert the coordinates into lat/lng for Leaflet.

Now to have [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) use the correct columns from your CSV file, you have to use the [`parser_options`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#api) (2nd parameter of your call to `omnivore.csv`), which are actually passed to the underlying library [csv2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson). These [options](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson#api) let you specify the latitude and longitude fields of your CSV file. For now you have only easting/northing, but we can convert them later on:

```js
var csv2geojsonOptions = {
  latfield: 'northing',
  lonfield: 'easting',
  delimiter: ','
}

omnivore.csv('./assets_cwy_new_simple.csv', csv2geojsonOptions);
```

Next, you need to convert your easting/northing coordinates into WGS84 lng/lat coordinates, using proj4leaflet. To have omnivore perform this conversion on each of your lines, you have to use the [`customLayer`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#custom-layers) (3rd parameter of your call to `omnivore.csv`). It is actually just a preconfigured [Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson). With this group, you can use its [`coordsToLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-coordstolatlng) option to implement your conversion with proj4leaflet:

```js
var customLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
  coordsToLatLng: projCoordsToLatLng
});

function projCoordsToLatLng(coords) {
  return lngLatToLatLng(proj4(osgb, wgs84, coords));
}

function lngLatToLatLng(lngLat) {
  return [lngLat[1], lngLat[0]];
}

omnivore.csv('./assets_cwy_new_simple.csv', csv2geojsonOptions, customLayer);
```

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Dj9Mukig8PAHUYinsapJ?p=preview