# How do I plot circle markers in Leaflet based off the coordinates in a CSV?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, leaflet

I am fairly new to html and leaflet. I am making a leaflet map using HTML and have a working code that is able to display many circle markers. However, I have hundreds of circles that need to be plotted onto my leaflet map. I am going to put all the data into a CSV and wanted to know how to reference the CSV in order to plot all the circles needed based on their x, y positions referenced in the CSV file.
Below is the working script I have so far (where I have to individually type out each position for each circle). The CSV file contains the location of each circle marker (x position in 4th column and y position in 5th column).

```
<body> <div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = L.map('map', {
crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    maxZoom: 7,
});
var bounds = [[0,0],[3002/3.6, 2761/3.6]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('/Users/rosaliaobrien/Desktop/fields/pdfs/ERSPRIME_img.pdf', bounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);

function onMouseMove(e) {
                                    x=(e.latlng.lng)*3.6;
                                    y=(e.latlng.lat)*3.6;
                                    y=Math.round(y);
                                    x=Math.round(x);
                                    r=(e.latlng.lng)*3.6*-0.000018816770169191928+53.09001347;
                                    d=(e.latlng.lat)*3.6*0.000016673923337433226-27.7399435; 


trackxy='<big> x, y: '+x+', '+y+'</big>';
trackRD='<big> RA, DEC: '+r+', '+d+'</big>';

                                    document.getElementById("tracker").innerHTML=trackxy;
                                    document.getElementById("tracker2").innerHTML=trackRD;

                                }
map.on('mousemove', onMouseMove);
var circle = L.circle([102/3.6, 1362.062438192257/3.6], {
color: 'red',
fillColor: '#f03',
fillOpacity: 0,
opacity: 10,
radius: 13
}).addTo(map);
circle.bindPopup("gid#47760: " + '<a href="/Users/rosaliaobrien/Desktop/Bio_pages/HTML_files/South/47760.html" target="_blank"> BIO PAGE</a>')
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide some additional information including code so we can better help you fix your problem

Comment: Done! Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your explanation sounds a bit confused to me, I think you would be interested in [load csv into leaflet and convert coordinates with proj4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902305/5108796)